# How can i answer "CallbackData" without use "AnswerCallbackQueryAsync" in telegram bot (C#)

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-bot

> the main problem is i want to send answer to user without showing by
>   notification or alert in telegram , and i want to show message in main
>   panel like other messages.

**This line of code just fire a notification**

```
  await api.AnswerCallbackQueryAsync(update.CallbackQuery.Id,"text");
```

**How can i response to callback like this line code?**

```
  await api.SendTextMessageAsync(update.Message.Chat.Id,"text");
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use that because this will stop **loading GIF** from telegram.

If you don't want to show alert, Leave `text` parameter `null` and it won't show alert.

then use `SendTextMessageAsync` method to send message to other messages.

Your code should be like this:

```cs
private void Bot_OnCallbackQuery(object sender, CallbackQueryEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Query.Data == "Hello")
    {
        string reply = "Hi!";

        // Answer with null parameter:
        await Bot.AnswerCallbackQuery(e.Query.Id, null);

        // Reply with message instead:
        await Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(e.Query.Message.Chat, reply);
    }

}
```